# Calculate cell values from previous rows in matlab with known initial value

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 12 matrices of 360 by 1000.

For each matrix, I'm trying to calculate the values for each row based on previous row values. The initial values for each column are known. I don't really know how to write the codes, could someone please help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear... Here is an example that might help:

```
%# pre-allocate matrix
M = zeros(360,1000);

%# initialize first row
M(1,:) = rand(1,1000);

%# compute remaining rows, one-at-a-time, using previous row
for i=2:size(M,1)
    M(i,:) = myFunction( M(i-1,:) );
end
```

where `myFunction` is a custom function that performs some sort of calculation on a row, and returns the new values for the next row. You could of course use more than one previous row each iteration, even all previous ones: `M(1:i-1,:)`